# IntelliJ IDEA How to bind regex replace to some key?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

IDEA have function for find and replace text in file (<kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd>) and supports regular expressions.

For example I write replace 1 to 2 and after this I need do it again, but I don't want write every time to fields what I want to replace.

Can I save it in list like live templates or bind on some key?

Comment: Tell IntelliJ you want to replace all.  It'll do them all at once.  If you can't do that, you'll have to make a decision one at a time.

Comment: You can try recoding a macros. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-macros-in-the-editor.html